# Error when switching laptop on

Tags: grub2

Have had lunch on my Dell laptop for quite a while and had a message there was a software update and I clicked install. When I came back and restarted the laptop all I get is the following message

error:invalid arch-independent ELF magic.
Entering rescue mode
grub rescue>

As I do not have any knowledge of Linux commands, as nothing seems to budge the screen from this error message.
Can someone please enlighten me as to what can be done to get the machine to load up and operate?

Answer (score 1):

> "Have had lunch on my Dell laptop for quite a while . . ."
>   Better to use a paper plate.

The quickest easy way to fix that is probably with one of the rescue disk utilities that you burn to a CD and boot from. Just get it and burn it on another computer. Or make a thumb version if you need to. There is RescuaTux, and, I think, SuperGrubDisk. I might not have those names exactly right, but search for "linux system rescue disks" and you should find them. You can even use an installation disk if that is all you have or can easily get. Just shrink some filesystem just enough to install and install a fresh system. It'll put in grub at the same time. That takes a while, and you have to have some space to spare but it has the merit that it is an easy trick to remember and someday you may need to do this without internet access, a crib sheet, or any other kind of rescue disk. You can also actually reinstall grub FROM the live system of a live disk, but the details of that I'd have to look up. You should be able to find instuctions easily enough though. Grub is a kind of quirky and breakage prone (I'm a lilo fan) so it isn't like you are the first to have this problem.

Comment: Okay, I do have the original lubuntu disk somewhere here which I will probably have to reload as at present there is no way to do anything but stare at the error screen. Predictive text on a smartphone is great isn'the it - should have been lubuntu. ...